# MySQL - If query returns error

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement

I want an if query like below.

```
set @i=1;
set @j=2;
if @i < @j then select * from test limit 1;
end if;
```

Im getting the below error,

```
1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'if @i < @j then select * from test limit 1' at line 1
```

Also tried this in procedure,

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test $$
create procedure test ()
set @i=1;
set @j=2;
if @i < @j then select * from test limit 1;
end if;
END $$


ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'if @i < @j then select * from test limit 1;
end if;
END' at line 1
```

Can anyone help me to fix this?

Comment: Unless this code is in a stored procedure or trigger, MySQL has no support for `IF..THEN` statements.

Comment: Type fixed, let me try this inside the proc.

Comment: in procedure also its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `begin`:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test $$
create procedure test ()
begin
    set @i=1;
    set @j=2;
    if @i < @j then
         select * from test limit 1;
    end if;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Your first doesn't work because `if` is only allowed in programming blocks.  In fact, that is why your version doesn't work either -- without the `begin` the `if` is not in a programming block.

Comment: thanks, but it didn't return any values. It'll go infinite while hit enter. call test(); 

    ->                                
    ->                                            
    ->                                   
    ->

Comment: Type `DELIMITER ;` afterwards to go back to the normal delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `IF`, put the test in the query:

```
SELECT * FROM TEST
WHERE @i < @j
LIMIT 1
```